# Why does Mixamo animation not work in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mixamo

I downloaded an animation from mixamo as I have always done. Imported it to Unity and added to my character animator as usual, but I only get a T-Pose. Even in the inspector and inside the game.
All the joints in the animation shows up like "mixamorig:LeftLeg", "mixamorig:Hips", maybe that's what causing the problem. But it has never been like that. Did the mixamo website change? Or is it a problem in my Unity?

I have already tried to change the "generic" rig to "humanoid" but it still doesn't work. Never needed to do it with other animations though.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably chosen this option while exporting from Mixamo (ie. without picking correct animation):

[image: Default settings]

You should pick the relevant animation in Mixamo interface and then download field changes it into:

[image: Animation picked settings]

(Without skin means that you will add animation only, without re-downloading the whole mesh)

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it still doesn't work.
Mixamo interface: https://prnt.sc/Y6vgbhGFHGIS
Unity interface: https://prnt.sc/jIdXNx2EI01q